# Failure to recognize the Arduino Mega2560 R2 board by the computer

Tags: breadboard, bootloader, isp

I am using an Arduino mega2560 R3 My Arduino port is not recognized by the computer.led on is green,leds Tx and Rx are yellow and led L is blinking constantly(According to the figure).I used an Arduino Uno to upgrade the Arduino Mega bootloader(According to the figure)  but the problem with the Arduino Mega board was not resolved.What do you think is the solution? Is the mega board burnt?[image]m[image: my mega2560]

I tested the communication cable, there was no problem.I also tested a UNO board that had no problems and was programmed by computer.

Comment: If the PC isn't recognising it then the problem is anywhere between the PC and the ATMega16U2 USB interface chip (the small square one by the LEDs).

Comment: I tested the communication cable, there was no problem.I also tested a UNO board that had no problems and was programmed by computer.

Comment: Did you test a different PC?

Comment: Then you should consider re-burning the firmware on the USB chip.

Answer (score 2):

The "L" LED is controlled by the main MCU. This is blinking because the bootloader is running fine. There is nothing (superficially) wrong with the main MCU.

The TX ad RX LEDs are controlled by the ATMega16U2 (or 8U2 or 32U2 depending on the board version) chip which forms the USB interface bridge. These being solidly on are a bad sign. Normally they would be off until some form of communication between the PC and the main MCU (via the 16U2) takes place. This is not happening. If it were a faulty cable then the LEDs would be off. If the PC were not configuring the port the LEDs would be off. But they're on. Therefore the fault is most likely with the 16U2 itself.

Either the chip has been physically damaged (maybe through overvoltage or other misuse) or it has "forgotten" its firmware, either again through misuse or having the firmware overwritten with something else (which can only happen if you specifically perform such an action through the programming header for that chip).

The first step of diagnosis is to try and communicate with that chip through the 6 pin header adjacent to it. You can do this in the same way as you do for programming the bootloader on the main MCU, but instead of programming a bootloader you program the 16U2's firmware (IIRC it's included with the IDE or the AVR core somewhere).

If that is successful and the LEDs start working correctly and the board starts to function again then it's cured. If not, then chances are the chip is dead.

If the chip is dead does that mean the board is dead? Not necessarily, no. It depends on how the board died. If only the 16U2 is dead and the main MCU is fine you can still use it, just not through the USB connection.  You could either use the TX/RX pins and your own external USB to UART interface to replace the 16U2 or program it through the ICSP (SPI) header using another Arduino or a dedicated USB programming dongle. It's less convenient, but means you can still use the board.

Comment: Insightful answer, great example of problem solving bit by bit. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Thanks for your full explanation